# Find strings which contain a substring from a given list

Tags: python-3.x

Given two arrays:

```
a = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
b = ['TOR_apple_impact', 'TOR_apple_staging', 'TOR_banana_impact', 'TOR_banana_STAGING', 'TOR_orange_IMPACT', 'TOR_orange_STAGING']
```

create a third list that contains the strings from list b which have a substring of any of the strings from list a. For the above arrays, the following would be returned:

```
c = ['TOR_apple_impact', 'TOR_apple_staging', 'TOR_banana_impact', 'TOR_banana_STAGING', 'TOR_orange_IMPACT', 'TOR_orange_STAGING']
```

Another example is shown below:

```
a = ['apple', 'banana']
b = ['TOR_apple_impact', 'TOR_apple_staging', 'TOR_banana_impact', 'TOR_banana_STAGING', 'TOR_orange_IMPACT', 'TOR_orange_STAGING']
# would return the following list.
c = ['TOR_apple_impact', 'TOR_apple_staging', 'TOR_banana_impact', 'TOR_banana_STAGING'
```

Here is what I tried

```
def build_systems_to_query(self, source_systems):
    systems_to_query = []
    for i in source_systems:
            systems_to_query.append('TOR' + '_' + i)
            systems_to_query.append('TOR' + '_' + i)
    return systems_to_query
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: List A has "orange". Why are those elements still omitted?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ updated the question.

Comment: Clearer now, thanks.

Comment: I did not downvote. I think your question is clear, but perhaps you can elaborate a bit on what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. Can I not ask a question when I have not figured out a solution? Does stackoverflow require to be used ONLY  if you have a solution? The downvoters and silent critiques make this site less effective.

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service; you're expected to do some thinking and research and have *something* to show for it before asking. See e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3001761. As to the complaining about comments, see e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/3001761; note that I *did* leave a comment, and you still haven't responded to it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're quick to act. You downvote, you vote to close the question. Maybe I did try which is why I asked this question on stackoverflow. Have some faith in the OP rather than attack attack attack. This makes me want to use this site less because of people like you.

Comment: @Crt Well, no, that's why people ask questions :-) However, we like to help users who've tried helping themselves first... that fosters a positive learning environment and discourages lazy people from using the site as a way out... not saying you're one of them, but there are people like that.

Comment: Maybe you did, but you didn't *show* that. Your question can only be judged by its content.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I understand but, seems counterintuitive that I have to post my code that does not work and is inefficient just to prove to others like jonrsharpe and earn his respect on a site which should avoid that stuff.

Comment: Also, try not to see downvotes as an attack. They're not personal. Everybody gets them. When you see them, think about what you may have been able to do better, then move on. Fussing about them is almost never constructive, but if you really feel the need to pursue, try Meta.

Comment: It's unclear how the code you've posted relates to what you're asking about; it seems to be creating a sort of `b` but full of duplicates, it's not obvious where `a` comes in. Also note that a [mcve] should include inputs and outputs, and actually be able to run (that looks like a method, but it's not in a class).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I wonder why I came to stackoverflow then... oh, maybe it was for help that coldspeed gave. Who would've known!

Comment: Sure, who doesn't want to get stuff written for them? I'm making these suggestions in the hope that they improve your *next* question, given that this one is resolved. It's not really worth complaining about a lack of comments if you're unwilling to hear what they say.

Comment: I am 100% willing if it makes sense. For example, for COLDSPEED he needed a clearer question which I updated. For you, I think your comments don't help as has been proven. You did absolutely nothing for this question. Question was clear after updating. I posted my attempt which I told you is not efficient or working which is why I came here. What don't you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
Pure python, *list comprehension*

```
>>> [i for i in b if any(j in i for j in a)]
['TOR_apple_impact',
 'TOR_apple_staging',
 'TOR_banana_impact',
 'TOR_banana_STAGING'
]
```

---

**Option 2**
`re.search`

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('|'.join(a))
>>> [i for i in b if p.search(i)]
['TOR_apple_impact',
 'TOR_apple_staging',
 'TOR_banana_impact',
 'TOR_banana_STAGING'
]
```